# Bootstrap Modal Form with Next/Previous Buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and coming from jQueryUI I was wondering if anyone has done a next/previous form interface to get around the whole scrolling viewport idea.

In the past I've worked with the following:

http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/

So before I get started I wanted to ask- also wanted to look out for any concerns with validation etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's untested, but a basic idea would be to include a tabbable nav into you modal body and add a prev/next button to every tab content something like this:

```
<form action="">
     <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
            <p>Form for section one</p>
            <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="btn pull-right">Next</a>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Next form part</p>
            <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="btn pull-left">Prev</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Another option would be to hide the `<ul>`-Tag and put your prev/next buttons into the modal footer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
```

should be

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a tutorial that adds a previous / next button to a photo gallery using Bootstrap 
http://fearlessflyer.com/next-and-previous-buttons-bootstrap-photo-gallery/

maybe you can use the same technique - using $(this).index().